# Detect 404 for resources via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

is there a way to detect resources on the page with response 404?

Also why the browser api- performance.getEntriesByType("resource") doesn't include the failed resources?

Comment: some resources, like images, you can tell by implication after examining its properties, but there's no one-stop place to get such info. you can also find resources via the dom and cross-check them with the entries API list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with this function :

```
function UrlExists(url) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        if (http.status == 404) {
             //  do something
        }
    }
```

And you pass the URL of your resource. but it's not the best solution ever to check this. Let's say it's the simplest :)

EDIT :

After you can also do it for every kind of resources (CSS, Images, ...), a function like this one :

```
var styleSheetExists = function(name) {
    for (var i in document.styleSheets) {
        if (typeof document.styleSheets[i] == "object") {
           link = document.styleSheets[i].href;
           if (link === null) {
               continue;
           }

           if (link.indexOf(name, link.length - name.length) !== -1) {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

That you can use like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(styleSheetExists('jquery-ui.css'));
    console.log(styleSheetExists('doesnotexist.css'));
});
```

(Source of the function : [How to check for 403 and 404 errors when changing the url of a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298617/how-to-check-for-403-and-404-errors-when-changing-the-url-of-a-resource))

and by checking every kind of resource, you can assure that there is or not a 404 status about them.

Comment: Nice but I think you wouldn't use it :)

Comment: Well let's say I would use it for 1 maybe 2 maximum resources that I really need to be sure about the 404 status. But for sure not on every resources ;)

Comment: look at my edit, I see something that can may be interesting for you :)

Comment: Thanks. Still I'm looking for more generic way to detect resources with 404

Comment: Well I think you can make a big function who will call the styleSheetExists,imageExists, ... just by detecting the extension of the parameter :)

And it will seems quite generic like : resourceExists(name) :)

Comment: Thank but I don't have a resource name, and also does the result of your function says that the resource came back with 404?

Comment: Well, it can check if the resource is accessible or not. If you need the HTTP status, then you need a HTTP call as in `function UrlExists(url)` unfortunately :/

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to use performance.getEnriesByType("resource")

Comment: Feel free to mark your problem as resolved if it is the case ;)

Comment: Sorry but it's still there. The challenge is still to detect resources that where not loaded successfully (even by dynamic JavaScript that loads an image)